# How to get Fiddler to filter specific localhost ports

Tags: localhost, fiddler

In a reverse of the usual request of how do I get Fiddler to capture requests to `localhost`, how do I stop it getting specific ports?

Since installing the IE 9 RC, I'm getting loads of requests to Mesh appearing ...

`http://localhost:2048/V4.0i/Sync/Devices/SDI6BHE6YYAHMR67S32S4MTROU/Endpoints`

I've tried adding locahost:2048 to the Fiddler Filters / Hide the following Hosts, but that's not working

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sussed it ... in Fiddler, open the custom rules with `Ctrl+R` and add to the `OnBeforeRequest` ...

```
if (oSession.host=="localhost:2048"){
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The version you're using doesn't support specifying the PORT in the Filters tab (that was added to v2.3.2.5).

In your version, simply put "localhost" in that box instead, or improve performance by preventing  loopback traffic from going to Fiddler at all. Click Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections. In the box at the bottom right, remove any <-loopback> token and instead add a  token. That token has no meaning to WinINET, but it tells Fiddler not to put the <-loopback> token in when it registers as the system proxy.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out all localhost requests on all ports open the custom rules with `Ctrl+R` and add the following to the `OnBeforeRequest` function

```
if (oSession.host.StartsWith("localhost:")) {
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
}
```

Save and close the rules editor, your changes will take effect immediately.

Comment: Does this add any additional insight 4 years after the original answer?